# reCaptcha in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recaptcha

I have installed the recaptcha gem from https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha and I have added the

```
<%= recaptcha_tags >
```

in my form before submit I have also place public and private key in environment.rb

```
ENV['RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
ENV['RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY'] = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXxx'
```

And my controller is like this

```
def create
  if verify_recaptcha
    super
  else
    build_resource
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error with the recaptcha code below. Please re-enter the code."
    render_with_scope :new
  end
end
```

I also followed the below link https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-Recaptcha-with-Devise since I also use it in my registration controller but every time the **verify_recaptcha** returns false can anyone plz tell me what I am missing

Answer (score 1):

I was successful using your code as a starting point with the following changes:

```
<%= recaptcha_tags >
```

should be:

```
<%= recaptcha_tags %>
```

which is added in your form before submit.

I set my environmental variables local by following option #3 here: http://railsapps.github.com/rails-environment-variables.html and set them on Heroku by following: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Finally in my controller:

```
def create
    if verify_recaptcha
       super
    else
       flash.delete(:recaptcha_error)
       flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error with the recaptcha code below. Please re-enter the code."
       render :new
    end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Judging by the code, if you want to use the environment variable way of configuring recaptcha, those environment variables must be set before recaptcha is loaded.

Since the gem will be required by bundler before your initialisers run, setting those environment variables in an initialiser is too late.

Why not use the

```
Recaptcha.configure do |config|
  config.public_key  = ...
  ...
end
```

approach ?